# How to setup a connection to MS SQL without /InstanceName in the address?

Tags: sql-server

How can I setup my SQL server to allow connections without having to type in the instance name? For example in the picture nelow, I'd like to connect without /SQLEXPRESS in the server name.

[image]

Comment: How will you be connecting to the server?  If it's a web app or something local you can use an alias: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1620/how-to-setup-and-use-a-sql-server-alias/.  This is a client based solution.  Otherwise, install a default instance.

Answer (score 2):

Install MSSQL without using a named instance.

Comment: Is there a way to correct this after install? Or set a default instance?

Comment: @Tyler No, you have to either uninstall the named instance and install as the default instance or just add the default instance (keeping the named instance).  There is no option to convert or to specify a specific instance as the default instance.  An instance is either the (one and only) default instance or it is a named instance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11921896/328536 is a solution that has worked for me, but thank you for your post as it has educated me.

Answer (score 2):

If on the client side you are using the SQL Server native client you can look at using an alias (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190445.aspx). This would have to be setup for each client connecting to that instance.

Alternatively as pauska mentioned, you would have to install this instance as a default instance.